# Maximum call stack size exceeded on an object JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I've been learning JavaScript for some time and so far I haven't encountered almost any problems.

Today I was studying the part related to getters and setters on objects and, when I started "revising" the topic, writing code on Visual Studio Code, I ran into this problem:

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` on "age" property

This is the code I've written so far:

```
let user = {
    name: "Fra",
    surname: "Emme",

    set age(value) {
        if (value < 18) {
            console.log(`${value} - You are underage :(`);
        } else {
            this.age = value;
        }
    },

    get fullName() {
        return `${this.name} ${this.surname}`;
    },

    set place(value) {
        if (value === "" || value === null || value.length <= 2) {
            console.log("Invalid place");
            return;
        }
        this.place = value;
    }
};

user.age = 20;
user.place = "Rovereto";

console.log(user);
```

I've searched the internet a bit, but all I find are solutions to problems related to recursion.

Could someone help me to solve the problem? So I also understand where I went wrong (if I was wrong).

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: Setting `this.age` *inside* the setter function for "age" will call the setter function again, because that's what having a setter function means.

Answer (score 0):

`user.age = 20` calls the `set age(value)` setter function. The `set age(value)` setter function then has the statement `this.age = value` which ends up calling the `set age(value)` setter function. Repeat this step until the max stack error you encountered. Consider setting an "internal" property, often conventionally indicated by an underscore (`_`) prefix:

```js
let user = {
    name: "Fra",
    surname: "Emme",

    set age(value) {
        if (value < 18) {
            console.log(`${value} - You are underage :(`);
        } else {
            this._age = value;
        }
    },

    get age() {
      return this._age;
    },

    get fullName() {
        return `${this.name} ${this.surname}`;
    },

    set place(value) {
        if (value === "" || value === null || value.length <= 2) {
            console.log("Invalid place");
            return;
        }
        this._place = value;
    },

    get place() {
      return this._place;
    },
};

user.age = 20;
user.place = "Rovereto";

console.log(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your setter for age your are setting age -> endless loop.
In your setter for place you are setting place -> endless loop.

*Remember:* You have created a setter - it will be called each time you set a new value to it. :)

If this was a class I would advice you to you use private members for storing the real values, since it isn't I've created two new properties _age and _place that we can use to store the values of age and place...

Here's the revised code:

```
let user = {
  name: "Fra",
  surname: "Emme",

  _age: 0,
  _place: '',

  set age(value) {
    if (value < 18) {
      console.log(`${value} - You are underage :(`);
    } else {
      this._age = value;
    }
  },

  get age() {
    return this._age;
  },

  get fullName() {
    return `${this.name} ${this.surname}`;
  },

  set place(value) {
    if (value === "" || value === null || value.length <= 2) {
      console.log("Invalid place");
      return;
    }
    this._place = value;
  },

  get place() {
    return this._place;
  }
};

user.age = 20;
user.place = "Rovereto";
```